# How do I know the current version in an android repo?

Tags: android, android-source

i.e. If I have done:

```
$ repo init -b froyo; repo sync
```

and I come back to this repo later, how can I determine which the version checked out is?
In other words, the response to:

```
$ "unknown command which I am looking for"
```

should be "froyo" in this case (or the respective version number), 
after:

```
$ repo init -b gingerbread; repo sync
```

it should be "gingerbread" (or the respective version number)

Answer (score 3):

You can open a `manifest.xml` file in your `.repo` hidden directory.
In the file you can find the following tag and value for gingerbread:

```
default revision="refs/tags/android-2.3.4_r1"
```

I do not know if it is an official way to do this.

Comment: I believe that this metadata is not mandatory for all projects, it is only an AOSP convention.

Answer (score 1):

**manifests.git**

Repo just downloads a given version of a git repository containing manifest files.

That repository is stored inside `.repo`, so you can check out its version with:

```
git --git-dir .repo/manifests.git log default
```

which shows me on the first line:

```
commit 985cbc6c03245ae454491a062a54afe9e7732d1e (tag: android-7.1.1_r6, origin/android-7.1.1_r6, m/android-7.1.1_r6, default)
```

**Get the SHA of all repos**

This command might also be useful, since branches appear to be moving and not sync all the subrepos:

```
repover() (
  # Print the revision of all repos.
  top="$(pwd)/"
  repo forall -c "pwd=\"\$(pwd)\"; echo \"\$(git log -1 --format=\"%H\") \${pwd#$top}\""
)
```

The output is of form:

```
c3e60f38c81a3dd4ff49dca0f05f84a8b464004f art        
293d4633af7d80584c7968c650bced857f338bc0 bionic     
80ccac2fffc09ef0b8a1fe43c096788e12359a1d bootable/recovery                                               
3aaf722a8d25ed726d4aba5d96bd325afe74a61c build/blueprint                                                 
cfcaaa25117310666e02a989a6bd9d45e82d8041 build/kati 
a7229a08b7c5d481cb813d810f1d88c3de3cdc8b build/make 
2e020842dc44bb67c3aad84217b3e6c4fa8fd900 build/soong
4cc6ccbeeed7d8ddcfb0fc955e523ba6d86e9601 compatibility/cdd                                               
34c43035d43004a23d34b1ae6651f6ea2107eb4c cts        
dd452a4244dad07c53db525d314fdcf4429ffd46 dalvik
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a `default.xml` file in the `/Working-Directory/.repo/manifests` path, and you can find something like this:

```
<default revision="refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r69"
       remote="aosp"
       sync-j="4" />
```

Please consider to reveal the hidden folder `.repo` in your working directory by pressing the `Ctrl+H` buttons.